# How to add CSRF to a custom front-end Magento Form (not using controller)

Tags: forms, magento, csrf

I'd like to know how I can implement CSRF protection on a custom Magento front-end form (in the mage system and located under app/design/.../templates/page/' folder as a .phtml file) that POST's to another custom PHP page (not in the mage system and located at the root of the Magento folder) to handle the form post, send email, etc.

I already have the custom forms and handlers working fine. I just need to add CSRF protection to these forms and need some advice on how I can do this using Magento's built in CSRF keys. I fully understand how to add the keys to the forms .phtml pages, but I am not sure how to use the _validateFormKey() function in the form handler's php page (since it is not in the mage system).

I am asking if this is possible as I do not want to have to create a custom module with front-end page to handle the task since the forms .phtml and handler pages are already setup and working (without CSRF). And yes, I have already looked at this post: [Magento CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945681/magento-csrf-protection/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once Magento application has been initialized you should be able to access Magento request and session objects and validate the form key in your PHP script:

```
$requestFormKey = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('form_key');
$sessionFormKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
if ($requestFormKey == $sessionFormKey) {
    //go
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The requestFormKey and the sessionFormKey values are different (without altering them manually via Firebug or MIM). How to use the _validateFormKey() function in the same scenario (a custom php handler page, not using mage or controllers)?

Comment: I gave up on trying to make this work using a non-module approach. Couldn't figure out how to get the keys to align that way. I decided to rebuild it in a magento module approach and using zlik's suggestion works fine. Use it in 'controllers/IndexController.php' action for CSRF protection on a custom front-end form. Thanks zlik! I also recommend checking out zlik's 'Top 5 magento secure coding best practices' slideshow [link]http://www.slideshare.net/magentodev/top-5-magento-secure-coding-best-practices-alex-zarichnyi[/link].